# Batch - Combining Two Pieces of Text on One Line in a Loop

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop, concatenation, filenames

I'm trying to work up a batch file to combine two pieces of text on one line.  The first is the filename; the second is the first line of text beginning with "To: ".  I have been struggling for hours and this is as far as I've gotten:

```
@echo off
IF EXIST fullnames.txt DEL fullnames.txt
FOR /F %%g IN ('dir /b *.eml') DO (
SET filename=%~f1
SET toline=FINDSTR /B /C "To: "
ECHO %FILENAME%%TOLINE% >> fullnames.txt
)
```

and it doesn't work.  I am getting errors or incorrect results almost regardless of what I put down for the filename line; haven't even begun to test the toline part.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You already used FOR /F to capture the output of the DIR command. Capturing the output of FINDSTR is no different.

However, it is more efficient to use a simple FOR in place of the FOR /F with the DIR command.

You used `%~f1` when I think you intended `%%~fg`.

You cannot expand a variable set within parentheses using %var%, you must use !var! delayed expansion instead. Type `SET /?` from the command line for more information - read the section starting with *"Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been
added..."*

However, in your case, you can easily avoid using delayed expansion (not that it is a problem).

Instead of deleting any existing "fullnames.txt" and then appending output to it, it is more efficient to enclose the entire construct within parentheses and redirect all output to the file using the over-write mode.

```
@echo off
(
  for %%F in (*.eml) do (
    for "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /b /c:"To: " "%%F"') do echo %%F %%A
  )
) >fullnames.txt
```

But the above solution, simple as it is, is much more complicated than it needs to be.

FINDSTR can process multiple files specified with wildcards, and it will prefix each matching line with the filename followed by a colon.

You can get your results simply from the command line without even using a batch file (or you could put this in a batch file):

```
findstr /b /c:"To: " *.eml >fullnames.txt
```

**Edit**
If you are concerned that a file might contain multiple lines starting with "To: ", and you only want to use the first line, then it is back to using a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "prevFile="
(
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /b /c:"To: " *.eml') do (
    if "%%A" neq "!prevFile!" echo %%A: %%B
    set "prevFile=%%A"
  )
) >fullnames.txt
```

The above solution could fail if a filename contains `!`. Also, a path could be used with `*.eml` as long as the path does not contain a drive letter. Both the drive and `!` issues can be resolved with additional modifications.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist fullnames.txt del fullnames.txt
for %%f in (*.eml) do (
   set toline=
   for /F "delims=" %%l in ('findstr /B /C:"To: " "%%f"') do (
      if not defined toline set "toline=%%l"
   )
   echo %%f!toline! >> fullnames.txt
)
```

**EDIT**: *Simpler method added*

The `set toline=` command delete 'toline' variable before each file is processed, so just the first "To: " matching line found is assigned to it and later shown using Delayed Expansion. However, this process may be achieved in a simpler way that doesn't require Delayed Expansion, as dbenham suggested:

```
@echo off
if exist fullnames.txt del fullnames.txt
for %%f in (*.eml) do (
   set firstFind=
   for /F "delims=" %%l in ('findstr /B /C:"To: " "%%f"') do (
      if not defined firstFind set firstFind=now & echo %%f%%l >> fullnames.txt
   )
)
```

Comment: Attempt to only process 1st "To: " line is bugged. Also, no need for delayed expansion. Within inner loop: `if not defined toline set toline=1&echo %%f%%l>>fullnames.txt`

Comment: @dbenham: Why you said the process of 1st "To: " line only is bugged?

Comment: Sorry Aacini, a stupid mistake on my part. The code works perfectly.

Comment: I have [a post](http://raywoodcockslatest.blogspot.com/2012/06/exporting-thunderbird-emails-to-pdf.html) containing the version I got to work, as applied to the problem of renaming EMLs exported from Thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign and use environment variables inside a for loop. Use delayed variable expansion or call a subroutine.

Delayed would look something like this

```
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

    @echo off
    IF EXIST fullnames.txt DEL fullnames.txt
    FOR /F %%g IN ('dir /b *.eml') DO (
    SET filename=%~f1
    SET toline=FINDSTR /B /C "To: "
    ECHO !FILENAME!!TOLINE! >> fullnames.txt
    )
```

However, that doesn't look like it would work correctly anyway.  I would do it like this

```
    FOR /F %%g IN ('dir /b *.eml') DO call :process %%g
    goto :eof

    :process
    SET filename=%~f1
    SET toline=FINDSTR /B /C "To: "
    ECHO %FILENAME%%TOLINE% >> fullnames.txt
```

Comment: But the `set toline=FINDSTR /B /C "To: "` will not _execute_ the `FINDSTR` command, it only assigns the text